# How do I detect if two variables have the same value

Tags: discord.py

I was making a discord bot and I want to make an account system, what my program supposed to do is to keep on finding a registered user by checking on the .json file over and over until it finds the two variable with the same value, problem is I can't find anything online for a solution. I just need a code for it :)

Comment: I am python noob plss help.

Comment: `if x == y:`. Maybe follow some tutorials as this is beginner level Python.

Comment: sorry, I'm now a C developer idk why I didn't follow a tutorial first before asking this stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Try something like this:

```py
with open('filenamehere', 'r') as f:
    # Add Code to add values to a list called x here
```

After this, we can go ahead and do one of two things:

1. Run a simple if value is in list x, or
2. Run a for loop on the list until it reaches the value required.
   Either way should give you the desired outcome. Sorry I was a little vague, your question was as well.

Comment: Thank You @weasel :)